# Are there any digital signatures valid for multiple pieces of data?

Tags: signature

Are there any digital signature algorithms that can be used to produce signatures valid for multiple pieces of data?

For example: Pick a private key $k_{private}$, which has public key $k_{public}$. Produce one signature $S$ which is valid for $h_1, h_2, \dots , h_N$, which are hashes of messages $m_1, m_2, \dots , m_N$.

Looking for a solution where the signature size is constant, or at least growing slowly as the # of messages increases. There may also be millions of messages, and they would typically be added one at a time.

I think you could do it with merkle signatures. I'm especially interested in solutions using elliptic curves.

Comment: Every signature algorithm which uses hash functions (ECDSA, for example) produces signatures which are valid signatures for different messages.

Comment: @Student20, but you could never find one :P I assume you're talking about the message space being larger than the hash space that the messages are mapped into. In order to use that, I'd have to break the irreversibility of a hash function, and if that can be done, then the scheme isn't secure because you could find infinitely many messages that are all valid for the same signature. I am looking to create signatures that are only valid for any one element in a defined, although appendable, set of elements. Each time you'd append, you'd produce a new signature that is valid for the N+1 elements.

Comment: Sometimes suffices finding collisions modulo some number. See Vaudenay's attack on DSA.  http://lasec.epfl.ch/pub/lasec/doc/Vau03a.ps You haven't specified what are values $h_i$. Are they arbitrary messages? Then Vaudenay's attack could work.

Comment: Another obvious solution is to use "composite" signature which consists of signatures of messages $h_1, \ldots, h_N$. Then you just check whether any of these signatures is valid signature of some message $h$.

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of what signature algorithms are meant to do. It would make the signature repudiable.  (Symmetric MAC algorithms quite often allow this. Signatures not so much.)

Comment: I don't see why hash trees would not work here. Just sign the root of the hash tree. If a hash tree doesn't suffice, *could you list additional requirements that you are looking for?*

Comment: @MaartenBodewes signing the root of a hash tree is a good idea! The problem is that now the signature consists of a normal signature plus a branch of the hash tree, and each hash requires a different branch, so there are still basically N signatures.

Comment: @otus how would it make signatures repudiable?

Comment: @StephenM347, if the same signature applies to several messages, you can claim you signed one of them and later claim you signed another. OTOH, with a signed hash-list or hash tree you've clearly signed them all so that is not the case.

Comment: @StephenM347 Is that a problem? With regards to space, a typical hash is 256 bits, while a secure RSA key is at least 3K bits (assuming that you want a relatively secure key for non-rep.). And it may include the root hash inside the signature. So your branch may need one or two hashes in addition to the signature. Main issue is of course that you need a protocol, but the efficiency in CPU and size should be minimal. (ECDSA signatures weigh in at twice the key size, giving you 512 bits minimum for a 256 bit key), so max double the key size for a depth of 3 nodes.